# Differential equation involving $f$ and its second derivative.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ a twice differentiable function such that:

$$[f''(x)+f(x)]e^x +1 =e^{2x}, \; f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$$

Find $f$.

What I've tried so far is:

$$\begin{aligned}
f''(x)e^x +f(x)e^x +1=e^{2x} &\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{x}f''(t)e^t \,dt+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)e^t\,dt+\int_{0}^{x}\,dt=\int_{0}^{x}e^{2t}\,dt \\ 
 &\Rightarrow  \left [ e^t f'(t) \right ]_0^x -\int_{0}^{x}e^t f'(t)\,dt+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)e^t\,dt+x =\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}-\frac{1}{2}\\ 
 &\Rightarrow  e^x f'(x)-\left [ f(t)e^t \right ]_0^x +2\int_{0}^{x}f(t)e^t\,dt +x =\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}+1\\ 
 &\Rightarrow  e^xf'(x)-e^xf(x)+2\int_{0}^{x}f(t)e^t \,dt +x =\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}+1\\ 
 &\Rightarrow  \frac{e^x f'(x)-e^x f(x)}{e^{2x}}+\frac{2\int_{0}^{x}f(t)e^t\,dt}{e^{2x}}+xe^{-2x}=\frac{1}{2}+e^{-2x}\\ 
\end{aligned}$$

but I cannot seem to go on. 
Any other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying the equation gives

$$f''+f=e^x-e^{-x}=\sinh x+\sinh x=\sinh x+\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sinh x$$

Thus a particular solution is $f_p(x)=\sinh x$. Moreover the general solution of
$$f''+f=0$$
is of the form

$$f_c(x)=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x$$

Hence the general solution is

$$f(x)=f_c(x)+f_p(x)=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x+\sinh x.$$

Now consider the initial data, $f(0)=0$ gives
$$c_1=0$$

$f'(x)=-c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x+\cosh x$, so $f'(0)=1$ gives
$$c_2=0$$

Thus

$$f(x)=\sinh x$$